# Horizontal Link drop downs falling under content CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, overlapping

I'm currently working on creating my first wordpress theme and I'm having trouble with the horizontal drop down. When hovering, the drop downs appear below the content.

http://pennyjarrdesigns.com/assets/problem1.jpg (screenshot)

I've tried using z-index and adjusting relative and absolute positioning and nothing seems to work. Adding absolute to the main div around the navigation produces this:

http://pennyjarrdesigns.com/assets/problem2.jpg (screenshot)

The drop downs are now visible but it breaks the layout.

**Here is the html/php:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelvecol last" id="nav">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav{background: #4b4261;
margin-bottom: 2%;
color: #f4e1c8;
 }

.nav{
width:100%;
background: #4b4261;
display:block;
float:left;
position:relative;
}

.nav ul{
list-style:none;
}

.nav li{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}
.nav a{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#f4e1c8;
padding:0 15px 10px 0;
font-size: 1.2em; 
font-weight:bold;
}

.nav ul ul{
display:none;
position: absolute;
left:0;
top: 100%;
float:left;
z-index:99999;
background: #c1c5cc;
}

.nav ul ul ul{
top: 30%;
left:100%;
background: #dfe1e8;
}

.nav ul ul a{
height:auto;
line-height:1em;
padding:10px;
width:130px;
}

.nav li:hover > a,.nav ul ul:hover > a{
color:#fff;

}

.nav ul li:hover > ul{
display:block;
 }
```

grid css:

```
.container {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

.row {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1140px;
min-width: 755px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;


}

.onecol, .twocol, .threecol, .fourcol, .fivecol, .sixcol, .sevencol, .eightcol, .ninecol, .tencol, .elevencol {
margin-right: 3.8%;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
}
```

I really feel like I'm overlooking something simple here. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the overflow for `.row` as hidden, which means, any content that extends past the borders of that element will not be shown.

Also, while you have the child ul element set as `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 9999;`, their parent elements are set to `position:relative;` do not have a z-index set to be above the `content` element.  Therefore, the drop down z-index only applies to its parent 'dimension' (z-index level) and not to the rest of the page.  This might cause a issue, but I haven't tested it, just working from memory.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I removed the overflow: hidden and added the z-index to the parent. Thank you!